# Vue Routes URL: username/pagename

Tags: firebase, vue.js, routes, backend, router

I create a website template with mock data by using vue & vuetify.
I have different pages like:

- localhost:8080/home
- localhost:8080/exp
- localhost:8080/skills
- localhost:8080/about

I would like to use this template for each user and change the structure to this:

- localhost:8080/**username**/home
- localhost:8080/**username**/exp
- localhost:8080/**username**/skills
- localhost:8080/**username**/home

I don't know whether this is the best practice and also I don't know how to do it.

I think that I will use firebase to store and get user related data. Also I am open for any suggestions.

When I go **localhost:8080/user/1** I can see everything in User.vue however when I go **localhost:8080/user/1/home** nothing is rendered. (**localhost:8080/home** works. I can see everything inside User.vue & Home.vue as well.

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home
        },
        {
          path: '/exp',
          name: 'exp',
          component: Exp
        },
        {
          path: '/skills',
          name: 'skills',
          component: Skills
        },
        {
          path: '/about',
          name: 'about',
          component: About
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

User.Vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        user
        <div>This is Bar {{ $route.params.id }}</div>
        {{personal.name}}
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'personal' }">Personal Info</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: take a look of child routes provided by `vue-router` https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: @kalidou.diagne 
I tried to do same things but I didn't work. I create User.vue and in router.js put all routes as a child of the User component. However I can not render anything. When I added **<router-view></router-view>** inside User.vue (it is also in App.vue) I can render all pages but in the previous url (without username) Also all lines in user.vue are rendered with the old pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the router. like this:

```js
{
  path: 'username',
  meta: { label: 'Username'},
  component: {
    render (c) { return c('router-view') }
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: 'exp',
      name: 'Exp',
      component: Cards
    },
    {
      path: 'about',
      name: 'About',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: 'other',
      name: 'Other',
      component: Other
    }
  ]
}
```

So u add childs to your path.. this makes the url look like /username/exp

Comment: I dont understand this line why we are using this. 
**render (c) { return c('router-view') }** 
When I add this children feature doesnt work. (I can render on the old url without username) I tried to create User.vue components and use User, instead of the line above. However this time I can not render anything. (both with and without username)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was using ' **/** home' in the path. This is why it goes **localhost:8080/home** instead of **localhost:8080/user/1/home**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'home',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home
        },
        {
          path: 'exp',
          name: 'exp',
          component: Exp
        },
        {
          path: 'skills',
          name: 'skills',
          component: Skills
        },
        {
          path: 'about',
          name: 'about',
          component: About
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

User.Vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        user
        <div>This is Bar {{ $route.params.id }}</div>
        {{personal.name}}
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'personal' }">Personal Info</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```